# Key.ENTER on an input does not submit

Tags: karate

I'm trying out Karate and have a use case where I need to trigger a search in a search box and there is no button to trigger the search, so it needs to be triggered via the enter key.

I have tried multiple different flavours of trying to provide `Key.ENTER` to the input to get it to work but none of them triggers it.

I am using the [latest](https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/download/v0.9.5/karate-0.9.5.zip) binary with a very basic feature file (altered to use google rather than an internal app URL):

```
Feature: Trigger search with enter

    Background:
        * configure driver = { type: 'chrome'}

    Scenario: Trigger Google search with enter

        Given driver 'https://google.com'
        # 1: Attempting to search with enter as an array argument
        When input('input[name=q]', ['karate dsl', Key.ENTER])

        # 2: Attempting to search with enter as a second command
        #When input('input[name=q]', 'karate dsl')
        #When input('input[name=q]', Key.ENTER)

        # 3: Attempting to search using similar approach to 1 but with a submit 
        #When submit().input('input[name=q]', ['karate dsl', Key.ENTER])

        Then waitFor('{h3}intuit/karate: Test Automation Made Simple - GitHub')
```

When using any of these approaches (by running `./karate <PATH_TO_ABOVE_FEATURE_FILE>`) the search results page never loads so the result (the `h3`) can never be found...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug for type `chrome`. It will actually work for type `chromedriver`.

Opened an issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1192

For now please workaround by using a click on the appropriate button / control etc.